# Symfony2 Gedmo Tree : how to update Tree path?

Tags: symfony, recursion, tree

I'm using materializedPath Tree with SonataAdmin in Symfony2. I've got a Category entity which uses trees. CRUD works but the path of children aren't updated :

Starting with :

- Cat1   with path = Root/Cat1
- Cat1.1 with path = Root/Cat1/Cat1.1
- Cat2   with path = Root/Cat2

Then I change Cat1's parent for Cat2 and I get :

- Cat1   with path = Root/Cat2/Cat1
- Cat1.1 with path = Root/Cat1/Cat1.1
- Cat2   with path = Root/Cat2

As you see, Cat1.1 path is wrong, it should be :

- Root/Cat2/Cat1/Cat1.1

How can I update parent's path to fix that ?
Thanks